# Markaby/Erector for Python

Tags: python, ruby, markaby

I like using Python, but hate writing HTML. Is there a Markaby/Erector - like module for Python?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can kind of do this with lxml:

http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#creating-html-with-the-e-factory

```
from lxml.html import builder as E
from lxml.html import usedoctest
html = E.HTML(
  E.HEAD(
    E.LINK(rel="stylesheet", href="great.css", type="text/css"),
    E.TITLE("Best Page Ever")
  ),
  E.BODY(
    E.H1(E.CLASS("heading"), "Top News"),
    E.P("World News only on this page", style="font-size: 200%"),
    "Ah, and here's some more text, by the way.",
    lxml.html.fromstring("<p>... and this is a parsed fragment ...</p>")
  )
)
```

There is also [Mimsy](http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/object-oriented-html/) which seems similar.

```
import makeHTML 
pageTitle = 'Hello World' 
pageHead = makeHTML.part('head') 
pageHead.addPart('title', content=pageTitle) 
pageBody = makeHTML.part('body') 
pageBody.addPart('h1', content=pageTitle) 
pageBody.addPart('p', content="Oh no, not again!") 
pageBody.addPart('hr') 
fullPage = makeHTML.part('html') 
fullPage.addPiece(pageHead) 
fullPage.addPiece(pageBody) 
fullPage.make()
```